# Do App Stores Have Exclusivity on Your Apps?

Tags: mobile, app

Let's say I write a mobile app and I want to sell it on all three:

1. Apple Market Place
2. Android Market Place
3. Windows Market Place

Will any of these market places tell me that it's not possible, that
in order to sell it I must only go through them and not through the
other ones?

p.s I know Angry Birds sells on all three. But how is that? I mean, don't books, for example, have exclusivity deals with their distributors?

Comment: If you can think of a single example of an app that is available in all three, then I don't think there's any automatic exclusivity. I'm not 100% sure, but I think Angry Birds is available in all three...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an interpretation of contracts between a developer and publisher (which may vary from developer to developer and publisher to publisher).

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

Those are different Platforms, So they are Different APPs!!

I think even if you sell on the Android APP store you can still also list your app in the Amazon Android App store. **Read the Terms of service to sure, as it can change any moment.**

Comment: What if I use PhoneGap, then I use the same language (javascript) to write for all three platforms?

Comment: @foreyez No, Same Source code, But different Compilers. One for each platform. See the FAQ: https://build.phonegap.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

In the interests of full disclosure, I work for Barnes & Noble. I do not own, nor do I plan to purchase stock of any of the companies I mention here.

You're confusing publishers and distributors. There are exclusivity deals with some games as well as some distributors functioning as publishers (Valve, Sony, Microsoft). However, in the case of books you have publishers like Random House or Simon & Schuster functioning as publishers who have exclusivity in most cases. There are cases where the hardcover and the paperback have different publishers, particularly if it's a reissue. The publisher-distributor combine in books is largely the purview of Barnes & Noble for paper books. B&N and Amazon both have ebook publishing programs.

So, while exclusivity is possible, it is not mandatory for the vast majority of apps.